# Disabling iCloud per app in iPhone Settings

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud

I am using iCloud key-value storage in my app (ios 5.0+) and I wonder if it is possible to turn it on/off from within Settings/iCloud, similar way we can turn off Facebook/Twitter (per app) ?

I would prefer not to implement my own popups etc.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Settings -> iCloud -> Documents and Data you can enable / disable use of iCloud for Documents and Core Data on a per app basis, but not for iCloud key value storage. 
If your app only uses iCloud key value storage it won't even appear in the list of apps on the settings pane.

So, the answer to your question is, no, it's not possible.